# how to adjust seekbar height programmatically in android

Tags: android

> In my android app i used a seekbar. And i try to adjust the height of the seek bar programmatically. Pls Refer my code below,

```
SeekBar Bar = null;
    Bar=new SeekBar(this);  
    Bar.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(dp(150), dp(20)));
    Bar.setMax(dp(100));
```

> if i use the above code, the seek bar shape in not perfect and it looks like half of thumb,
>   How to get the proper shape, pls guide me,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By using thumb we can able to change the shape of the seekbar. Sample code is given below,

```
 float[] outR = new float[] {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6};  
    ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outR, null, null));      
    thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(dp(30));
    thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(dp(6));    
    thumb.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
  Bar.setThumb(thumb);
```